# Auto Delete JULI Log files

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

While using Tomcat in my application, when i import file from a location and stop my application in the middle, JULI log files are generated. How to auto delete them as they just get created and are not destroyed.

Is there any configuration to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. It is obviously possible to disable any logging in JULI. JULI is an implementation of Java util Logging, see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) for the details. This is configured in the *logging.properties* file located in the *conf* directory of Tomcat. But only your applications calls to Java util Logging are responsible for JULI logs.

I would suggest that your problem is in the application log calls, not in the configuration anyway.